# How do I figure out what software tool was used to create an "setup.exe"so I can determine what the silent parameters are?

Tags: sccm, automated-install, setuptools

I have a situation where many users can submit "setup.exe" to be deployed on all our user workstations. We use SCCM to perform the setups. We would like to have these setup.exe's execute silently and with logging. We cannot expect the users to provide this information (this is a requirement).

My current thoughts are if we can figure out what installation tool was made to create the EXE (Install Shield, WISE, WIX, etc...) we can make a reasonable guess at the parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Indirectly via searching for text inside of the setup.exe like this:

1. InstallShield:
   powershell command: 
   `strings.exe .\AcrobatProfessional_7.0_EN\setup.exe | select-string "InstallShield"`

If the Setup.exe was created by
"Installshield"
then the command abbove will probably find text like this:
"This Setup was created with a BETA VERSION of InstallShield Developer"

2. Inno:
   powershell command: 
   `strings.exe .\AcapelaTexttoSpeechClient_8.2.5.3_EN\setup.exe | select-string "inno"`

If the Setup.exe was created by 
"Inno Setup"
then the command abbove will probably find text like this:
"This installation was built with Inno Setup."

3. WISE:
   powershell command: 
   `strings.exe .\AcapelaTexttoSpeechClient_8.2.5.3_EN\setup.exe | select-string "InstallAware"`

If the Setup.exe was created by 
"Wise Setup"
then the command abbove will probably find text like this:
"This installation was built with InstallAware: http://www.installaware.com"

the parameter -pattern of cmdled select-string accept array of strings so the command can be universall for all the tests like this:
strings.exe '...path to exe' | Select-String -Pattern @("InstallAware","inno","InstallShield")

strings.exe -> (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/strings)

select-string -> (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string?view=powershell-5.1)